# Pyinstaller for module script

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

Im trying to make my script an .exe using pyinstaller.

I currently run my scrip like this

```
Python -m script.script -c config.ini
```

Is it possible to use pyinstaller if so how?

I have tried the following

```
Pyinstaller python -m script.script
```

But no luck.

Have also tried building  *script.py* by its self but as it calls other scripts from other folders it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using py2exe so scrpit sended up as

```
Scrpit.exe -c settings.ini
```